# json twitter query, parse to html feed

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitter

i am trying to build a hastag feed for twitter,
i already have read how to create the search query, and i have this json structure...

```
{
  "completed_in": 0.026,
  "max_id": 201961894368653313,
  "max_id_str": "201961894368653313",
  "next_page": "?page=2&max_id=201961894368653313&q=wearetwo&lang=en&rpp=100&include_entities=1",
  "page": 1,
  "query": "wearetwo",
  "refresh_url": "?since_id=201961894368653313&q=wearetwo&lang=en&include_entities=1",
  "results": [
    {
{
      "created_at": "Sat, 12 May 2012 01:06:19 +0000",
      "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
          {
            "text": "wearetwo",
            "indices": [
              12,
              21
            ]
          }
        ],
        "urls": [

        ],
        "user_mentions": [
          {
            "screen_name": "crifor",
            "name": "Cristina Forlani",
            "id": 110646291,
            "id_str": "110646291",
            "indices": [
              3,
              10
            ]
          }
        ],
        "media": [
          {
            "id": 201101250740240387,
            "id_str": "201101250740240387",
            "indices": [
              34,
              54
            ],
            "media_url": "http:\/\/p.twimg.com\/Asp0haZCQAMC-Sq.jpg",
            "media_url_https": "https:\/\/p.twimg.com\/Asp0haZCQAMC-Sq.jpg",
            "url": "http:\/\/t.co\/1EXkTMYq",
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/1EXkTMYq",
            "expanded_url": "http:\/\/twitter.com\/crifor\/status\/201101250740240384\/photo\/1",
            "type": "photo",
            "sizes": {
              "small": {
                "w": 340,
                "h": 455,
                "resize": "fit"
              },
              "large": {
                "w": 765,
                "h": 1024,
                "resize": "fit"
              },
              "thumb": {
                "w": 150,
                "h": 150,
                "resize": "crop"
              },
              "orig": {
                "w": 765,
                "h": 1024,
                "resize": "fit"
              },
              "medium": {
                "w": 600,
                "h": 803,
                "resize": "fit"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "from_user": "stevoltan",
      "from_user_id": 165713968,
      "from_user_id_str": "165713968",
      "from_user_name": "Stefano Voltan",
      "geo": null,
      "id": 201116057396719616,
      "id_str": "201116057396719616",
      "iso_language_code": "en",
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "recent"
      },
      "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2163464409\/crepes_normal.jpg",
      "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2163464409\/crepes_normal.jpg",
      "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/twitter.com\/#!\/download\/iphone&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Twitter for iPhone&lt;\/a&gt;",
      "text": "RT @crifor: #wearetwo belle facce http:\/\/t.co\/1EXkTMYq",
      "to_user": null,
      "to_user_id": 0,
      "to_user_id_str": "0",
      "to_user_name": null
    },
```

I need to extract the media url and text... can someone please help me.. i'm really new to this... i'd appreciate if you could show me a working example of this..at least the function...

Comment: Have you actually got this JSON back in a object by using something like $.getJSON?

Comment: I have used this service here...
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu
and this is the query i added...

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=wearetwo&lang=en&result_type=recent&rpp=100&include_entities=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This documentation will show you how to get the data into a format you can work with using jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Something like:

```
$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=wearetwo&lang=en&result_type=recent&rpp=100&include_entities=true', function(data) {
  var media_url = data.results.media.media_url;
  var text = data.text;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been reading about this, about 3 hours... sorry, i might seem stupid but this is all new to me.. how can i apply this?... How can i append it to html?... Can you please show me how to build the function?

Comment: I wont be writing your code for you. You need to look at learning basic javascript or jQuery. Or at least post what you have tried (and accept my answer)